# Is is possible to get a log of the recent actions done in Thunderbird (Delete/Archive/Junked/..)

Tags: thunderbird

I archived a few emails by error in Thunderbird and `Ctrl-Z` is not working. What I would love is to have a list of the recent actions like this:

```
Archived Mail XXX
Archived Mail YYY
Deleted Mail ZZZ
```

So I can find the email I archived by error

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is Tools > Activity Manager. But it won't show you which messages have been changed.

Comment: Yup, my actions showed up there but not detailed enought to recover my emails, but thanks, I guess I need to make my own addon